# Using TC from iproute, unable to match canid

Tags: linux, networking, iproute2

I'm trying to use `tc` from `iproute2` to prioritize packets sent to a canbus.

Before doing so I read this guide about the issue: http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/can/socketcan-qdisc-final.pdf

Even using the exact examples from that pdf, I'm not able get any of the filters to get a match. My current version of kernel and `tc` only allows me to use the u32 match option.

Tried (both big and little endian):

```
tc filter add dev can0 parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match u32 0x01000000 0xffffffff at 0 flowid 1:1
```

and also:

```
tc filter add dev can0 parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match u8 0x01 0xff at 4 flowid 1:1
```

Sending packets to fit those filters does not trigger a match. I'm a bit confused why exact examples from the guide does not seem to work.

Any hints or experience on this would be much appreciated.